# Search 2D array for matching variable

Tags: javascript

This should be easy but my brain is fried.

I have a variable, and I want to search a 2D array that corresponds to matching value:

```
const fruits = [
["bananas", 123],
["strawberries", 456],
["kiwi", 789],
["mango", 098],
["apple", 543],
];

const input = "apple";

// result should be 543
```

What would be the shortest way to do so?

Comment: Why are you using a 2D array instead of an object or Map? If you use an object you can just do `fruits[input]`

Comment: I'm pulling this from Google Sheets, and in Google Apps Script it comes in as a 2D array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use the `find()` method to search for the matching value in your array.

For example:

```js
const fruits = [
  ["bananas", 123],
  ["strawberries", 456],
  ["kiwi", 789],
  ["mango", 098],
  ["apple", 543],
];


const input = "apple";

const result = fruits.find(fruit => fruit[0] === input)?.[1];

console.log(result); // 543
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) depending on how many results you expect.

In case there are no results, `find()` returns `undefined` and `filter()` returns an empty list, so it's easy to check for results.

```js
const fruits = [
["bananas", 123],
["strawberries", 456],
["kiwi", 789],
["mango", 098],
["apple", 543],
];

const input = "apple";

// multiple results
const results = fruits.filter(x => x[0] === input);
if(results.length !== 0){ // check if we have at least one result
  console.log(results.map(x => x[1])); // instead of whole array, only log the number
}
// single result
const result = fruits.find(x => x[0] === input);
if(result !== undefined){ // check if we have a result
  console.log(result[1]); 
}
```

Another way, better suited if you want to do multiple lookups is to convert the 2D array to a JS object (using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)) or [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which can do lookups more efficiently in constant time `O(1)` as opposed to linear time `O(n)`.

> For this approach to work the keys (i. e. the fruit names in your example) need to be unique, so this only works for a single result.

```js
const fruits = [
["bananas", 123],
["strawberries", 456],
["kiwi", 789],
["mango", 098],
["apple", 543],
];

const input = "apple";

// Approach with JS object
// convert to JS object
const fruitsObj = Object.fromEntries(fruits);
// lookup in the object using the key
console.log(fruitsObj[input] ?? "Not found");


// Approach with Map
const fruitsMap = new Map(fruits);
// lookup in the Map using the key
console.log(fruitsMap.get(input) ?? "Not found");
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to convert your array from Google Sheets into an object like this:

```js
const fruits = [
  ['bananas', 123],
  ['strawberries', 456],
  ['kiwi', 789],
  ['mango', 098],
  ['apple', 543],
]

const fruitsObject = fruits.reduce(
  (accumulator, currentValue) => ({
    ...accumulator,
    [currentValue[0]]: currentValue[1],
  }),
  {}
)

console.log(fruitsObject)
console.log(fruitsObject['bananas'])
```